# Ajax issue while creating PHP pages and Popup window for user input

Tags: php, ajax, html

Actually I have to create one page that is showing all employee information like (name,age,salary,etc) and one add button. If i clicked on add it will open one pop up window which will take user input of (name,age,salary); after submit it will update my database and my first page without refreshing the page.

i have created 3 file.

1) Display.php where i have to display employee information and add button.

2) Add.html i passes this file to popup method on click of add button.

3) Update.php where i wrote database query on action of submit button.

Now i am confused where i should write Ajax ? that will help me to display the record on my first page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You only need 2:

1. Display.php in here you display the info and add button, have a seperate `<div>` that is hidden but shown with an`onClick` javascript function. In this div you have your submit button which will fire the ajax query.

2.Update.php This will receive the ajax query and return the new data to the first page.

You can put the javascript functions in their own file and call them into display.php if you want.